# Geocoder return wrong result. What can i do?

Tags: google-maps

The result of geocoding 
[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Москва&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&sensor=false)
should be

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Москва",
               "short_name" : "Москва",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Московская область",
               "short_name" : "Московская область",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Россия",
               "short_name" : "RU",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Москва, Московская область, Россия",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 56.0213690,
                  "lng" : 37.9650910
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 55.490520,
                  "lng" : 37.1303210
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 55.74279280,
               "lng" : 37.61540090
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 55.94326550,
                  "lng" : 38.12763850
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 55.54128490,
                  "lng" : 37.10316330
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

But  it return "Курганская область" instead of "Московская область"...
How to make the google map team correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "report a problem" link in the lower right hand corner of the map at maps.google.com

See this issue in the issue tracker:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4208